# Laravel Public folder accessible on LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, lamp

I am in dire need of help with setting up my laravel project on a LAMP server.
So far I have tested my "Pretty URLs" on my localhost xampp server with no problems. Now that I am trying to set it up on an actual LAMP server I am running into issues

So far I have installed the LAMP services (Ubuntu, Apache2, MYSQL, PHP5 (with curl and mcrypt)). Currently I have my laravel project in my home directory with a symlink to the public folder in my /var/www/html folder like so... [project](http://puu.sh/igEcZ/560d0707f2.png), [symlink](http://puu.sh/igEh5/934c75b3a5.png).

I have changed my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf with following config

```
<Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I then used the command, `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and edited my .htaccess file as per the instructions in the laravel docs.

Finally, I restarted my apache service: `sudo service apache2 restart`, and when I attempt to go to "mydomain.com/public" I receive a 403 forbidden error.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?

Comment: You wouldn't access `/public` in your browser, just `/`.

Comment: I made a mistake in typing the post...
"I have changed my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf so to look like this http://puu.sh/igEnN/22069d76b6.png."

Comment: @StuartWagner My Document Root is "/var/www/html" wouldnt that meant I should include the "/public". Either way it still doesnt work when I try to access my urls from routes.php I get the resource isn't found

Comment: You have to point your DocumentRoot at the `public` folder, because that's where Laravel's `index.php` lives.

Comment: @StuartWagner I changed my document root to the public folder, my "pretty URLs" from "routes.php" still do not work

Comment: Make sure you have your `.htaccess` is set up correctly. All requests need to be pointed at `index.php` so Laravel can capture them.

Comment: My .htaccess file is like snippet posted on www.laravel.com/docs/5.0 that is said to be used if the original does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `Apache` configuration, it seems to be fine. What I prefer is to disable Indexes (to prevent the directory listing) and MultiViews (to prevent implicit filename pattern match).

```
<Directory /var/www/html>

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    #some general directives could be handy here also
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|jp?g|gif|ico|mp4|wmv|mov|mpeg|css|map|woff?|eot|svg|ttf|js|json|pdf|csv)">
            ExpiresActive on
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 weeks"
    </FilesMatch>

</Directory>
```

**The problem seems to be permission related.** By default the `Apache` runs as `www-data:www-data`. This could be changed in `envvars` (changes should be followed by `Apache` restart) or during provided as compile time option. The `/etc/apache2/envvars`

```
...
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
...
```

However, a nicer way would be

- change the group of `/var/www/html` to `www-data` with `sudo chown :www-data /var/www/html`
- change the mode of `/var/www/html` to `2770` with `sudo chmod 2770 /var/www/html`. Since `Apache` needs execute permission to access the directory. Apply this command to other directories recursively
- change the mode of your *public* directory static files to `2660` for safety measures